# Relationship Field ACF multiple Post Types

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make a query between two post types to build a page that shows 05 news. This query will get the name of the news, with the post type “post” and the name of the journalist who wrote the news along with his photo with post type “journalist”. I'm using relational field in ACF. I'm used to using the ACF, however, this is my first time working with a relational field. I can't seem to get the information to appear. Can someone help me? I managed to assemble the code below, but I'm kind of lost, I've searched in several places on the subject but I can't understand. Here is the code I made below:

```
<!--Start Relationship-->
                       <?php 
                        $ids = get_field('notices', false, false);
                        $query = new WP_Query(array(
                            'post_type'         => 'posts',
                            'posts_per_page'    => 5,
                            'post_status'       => 'any',
                        ));
                      ?>
<!--End relationship-->
                        <div class="col-3"><img src="<?php the_field(‘photo') ?>" class="photo"></div>
                        <div class="container-reporter col-8">
<div class="name-reporter"><?php echo the_title(); ?></div>  (name reporter )                           <div class="key-notice"><?php the_field(‘key_notice') ?></div>                            <div class="text-reporter"><?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_the_title(), 0, 60, '...' ); ?></div>  (title notice)
                       </div>
```

I need help to finish building a query with two types of Post Types with ACF relational fields.

Comment: I had an answer, but deleted it after re-reading your question. It's a bit unclear what you have. Do you have a post type called "journalist"? How is that related to the "post" post type? Where are you trying to output this information? You also have a bunch of errors in your code snippet - using back-ticks `\`` instead of `'` single quotes around your key/variable names.